# How to configure port for Node.js Application in Cpanel?

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

I want to run a Node.js Express app together with Apache configured by CPanel

Instructions for "CPanel How to Install a Node.js Application" describe setting up an Express app listening on port 3000. 
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+a+Node.js+Application. But CPanel >> Home >> Software >> Application Manager has no input to enter the port where requests should be forwarded.

The running Express app responds to curl http://127.0.0.1:3000

Expected a request to url http://example.com/nodejsapp to receive a response from the Node.js App but get a 404 Error instead. Should forwarding to a particular port be included ?

Answer (score 5):

You mush config **.htaccess** :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/$1 [P,L]
```

with XXXXX is your port .

Comment: The express app is listening on 3000 should both sets of XXXX be 3000 ? Where is that port number set up in the CPanel Application Manager ?

Comment: No, you must config in .htaccess and you can set port server at `server.js` (file contain your server code) . Then you want run at port 3000 , you must set `XXXXX` to 3000

Comment: Implemented that but still getting a 404

Comment: I beleive you must contact your hosting provider. Because It is including server config . Tell me problem after contact your hosting provider .

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. Running React/Next SSR application on Fast Comet.